# Matching with ignore specific symbols

Tags: regex

My expression for matching is `\Qbar0\E`

I try to ignore specific symbols, such as `0|`

I need to find matches in the word not considering specific symbols

For example:

1) Search matches in the `foobar0` - matches should be found

2) Search matches in the `foobar0|` - matches should be not found

3) Search matches in the `foobar0|0` - matches should be not found

This case can be done with regex?

Comment: What do you mean with "specific symbols"? Are there more to consider? Can you also further define what `Q` stands for and what a valid input would be? In what application are you working btw?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.". Could you give more context?

Comment: It's a non-sense to surround `bar0` with `\Q...\E`, there're no special char in it.

Comment: Is [that](https://regex101.com/r/w65d6z/1) what you want?

Comment: I think the question is too vague to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I well understand, but using a negative lookahead will do the job:

```
bar0(?![|])
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/w65d6z/1)